# React child component not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following (slimmed down) components:

```
export class StringExpression extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const fieldOptions = getFieldOptions(this.props.expression);

    console.log(fieldOptions); //I can see fieldOptions changes here

    return (
       <Expression {...this.props} className="block-container">
         {fieldOptions ?
           <Popover>
             <PopoverTarget>
               {expression.value}
             </PopoverTarget>
             <PopoverContent id={expression.id}>
               <SelectList fields={fieldOptions} />
             </PopoverContent>
           </Popover> :
           <InlineEdit />
         }
       </Expression>
    );
  };
}

export class SelectList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.fields.map((field, index) => {
          return <li key={field} onClick={this.handleClick}>{field}</li>;
        }
      </ul>
    );
  };
}
```

When I change input for `StringExpression`, I'm seeing that that component re-renders.  These are changes that alter what `fieldOptions` is which is a prop of `SelectList`.  `SelectList` is not re-rendering, though.  I tried adding `this.forceUpdate()` on `StringExpression` (which I believe is not wise).  I also added `componentWillReceiveProps()` to `SelectList` to see if it fires when `fieldOptions` changes, but it doesn't.

How can I get `SelectList` to re-render on `fieldOptions` change?

**UPDATE**
I updated my post to share additional code of my `StringExpression`.  As you can see, `SelectList` is conditionally displayed based on `fieldOptions`. `SelectList` renders when `fieldOptions` changes from `null` to `string[]`, or vice versa.  This is because `SelectList` unmounts so `InlineEdit` can mount.  If `fieldOptions` changes from one `string[]` to another, `SelectList` does not rerender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `key={field}`. If I'm guessing right, `field` is an object with different properties (does it have an `id`?). So the `key` each `li` is getting is `[object Object]`.

Keys should be unique for every array element, and in this case they aren't, so React doesn't really know how to render them, especially if every one has the same key.

Try using `key={field.id}` or some other unique property for that. You could use the `index` if no unique key exists for that field.

Comment: `fields` is a `string[]`.

Comment: My bad. Didn't notice the `<li>{field}</li>`.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for taking time to give a suggestion.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: That example code *should* update. Is `fieldOptions` really changing? Maybe `this.props.expression` changes and triggers a `StringExpression` re-render, but does `getFieldOptions(this.props.expression)` really change?

Answer (score 0):

For what i see about your code, the explanation must be that your prop field on your select list component don't change during the runtime. you're problem seems to be somewhere else. 
give us more information about your code

Comment: I shared a bit more of my code.  As you can see, there is conditional rendering in `StringExpression`'s `render()`.